# C# - DateTime.TryParse issue - why doesn't it like my string representation of my date?

Tags: c#, datetime, tryparse

Here's my code:

```
            DateTime Dob = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/1800");
            DateTime Dod = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/1800");

            if (!DateTime.TryParse(p.birthday, out Dob) && !DateTime.TryParse(p.deathday, out Dod))
            {
                // handle error
            }
```

`p.birthday` is:

[image]

`p.deathday` is:

[image]

When the `.TryParse()` code hits, my `DateTime` object for Dob is:

[image]

And the `DateTime` object for Dod is:

[image]

**QUESTION**: Why is `Dod` still "1-1-1800" (the initial value I assigned), but `Dob` is set correctly?  Is there something about the Dod value of "2007-02-28" that it doesn't like?

Comment: what is your current culture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime.TryParse(p.birthday, out Dob)` successfully converts the `string` to `DateTime`, so it returns true.  You invert this with `!`, giving false.

When the execution gets to the `&&` operator, it sees the first operand is already `false`, so doesn't bother executing the second operand.

You could either execute both beforehand, or use the non-shortcut AND operator, `&`.

Edit: Or

```
if (!(DateTime.TryParse(p.birthday, out Dob) || DateTime.TryParse(p.deathday, out Dod)))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that its executing !(DateTime.TryParse(p.birthday, out Dob) and returning false.
Therefore !DateTime.TryParse(p.deathday, out Dod) is not executed.

According to

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx

x && y

if x is false, y is not evaluated, because the result of the 
AND operation is false no matter what the value of y is. This is known as 
"short-circuit" evaluation.
```